# Replace namespaces and files name from a github template repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, replace

I have a template repository in github, every time i'm in need to code something with that pattern i do this:

- clone it to a new project in Visual Studio
- manually replace every "Template" in the project to its name, for example, the file names and the namespaces inside the template .cs files

But it takes a long time to replace it all and often leads to some mistakes. I want to know if there is a tool to replace everything automatically or some kind of extension to do this.

It is a C# template to a DDD project. I'm currently coding with Visual Studio 2022

Thanks for the help!